# Как показывать только 3 строки по умолчанию, а всю таблицу только при нажатии кнопки "показать всю"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть рейтинг на сайте

```
    <div id="rating" class="rating"> 
        <table id ="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>№</th> 
                    <th>Фамилия Имя</th> 
                    <th>Очки</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody class="selected"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>1</td> 
                    <td>Мацюк Александр</td> 
                    <td>280</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>2</td> 
                    <td>Мурзин Максим</td> 
                    <td>135</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>3</td> 
                    <td>Тюков Владимир</td> 
                    <td>85</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>4</td> 
                    <td>Гаврилов Константин</td> 
                    <td>80</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>5</td> 
                    <td>Кутя Сергей</td> 
                    <td>80</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>6</td> 
                    <td>Кислань Елизавета</td> 
                    <td>72</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>7</td> 
                    <td>Моисеенко Александр</td> 
                    <td>61</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>8</td> 
                    <td>Краснов Денис</td> 
                    <td>60</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>9</td> 
                    <td>Кислань Сергей</td> 
                    <td>59</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>10</td> 
                    <td>Кулага Илья</td> 
                    <td>59</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Как сделать, что бы показывало на странице только ТОП3 и при нажатии на кнопку(ее пока нет) "показать весь рейтинг" открывало весь рейтинг.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например вот так:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('showAll');
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Проверяем на наличие класса и  вызываем соответсвуюущую функцию
  table.classList.contains('opened') ? hideRows()  : showRows();
});

function showRows() {
  table.classList.add('opened');
  button.innerHTML = 'Скрыть';
}
function hideRows() {
  table.classList.remove('opened');
  button.innerHTML = 'Показать всё';
}
```

```css
.tablesorter tbody tr {
  display: none;
}
.tablesorter.opened tbody tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(1),
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(2),
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(3) {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
 <div id="rating" class="rating"> 
 <table id ="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead> 
   <tr> 
    <th>№</th> 
    <th>Фамилия Имя</th> 
    <th>Очки</th> 
   </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody class="selected"> 
   <tr> 
    <td>1</td> 
    <td>Мацюк Александр</td> 
    <td>280</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>Мурзин Максим</td> 
    <td>135</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>3</td> 
    <td>Тюков Владимир</td> 
    <td>85</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>4</td> 
    <td>Гаврилов Константин</td> 
    <td>80</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>5</td> 
    <td>Кутя Сергей</td> 
    <td>80</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>6</td> 
    <td>Кислань Елизавета</td> 
    <td>72</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>7</td> 
    <td>Моисеенко Александр</td> 
    <td>61</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>8</td> 
    <td>Краснов Денис</td> 
    <td>60</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>9</td> 
    <td>Кислань Сергей</td> 
    <td>59</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>10</td> 
    <td>Кулага Илья</td> 
    <td>59</td> 
   </tr> 
  </tbody> 
 </table> 
  <button id="showAll">Показать всё</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы используете jQuery, то можно вот так: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/bWLzRw

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает! К сожалению не могу поставить стрелочку вверх, так как не хватает репутации(нужно 15, а у меня 11). Если Вы поставите плюс моему вопросу, то как раз хватит, что бы я Вам поставил.

Comment: @КулагаИлья - галочка слева от ответа - щёлк :)